# How to add a file to Request.Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In order to simulate a submission of a file (for testing purposes), I need to add a file to `Request.Files` in the Controller.

`Request.Files` is an `HttpFileCollectionBase` but it doesn't seem to expose a method to add a file to it.

How do I add a file to this collection?

Greg

Comment: Usually a posted file is an argument on the controller, which can then be mocked for testing.  It sounds like the controller code is coupled to `HttpContext`, which as you can see makes testing difficult.

Comment: @David, You are exactly right.  The issue is that a component (which I do not have the source for) does the actual processing of the file directly off of the HttpContext.  Thus I am trying to stuff a file in there.

Comment: In that case the ideal approach would be to mock that component to remove the dependency.  (Not only the dependency on `HttpContext` but also the dependency on that third party component.)  That way you can test your logic without relying on external dependencies.  In order to test the component itself (which *shouldn't* be necessary, the vendor should handle that) that would be more of an integration test, or possibly a manual QA test.  `HttpContext` is notoriously difficult to manually invoke, it is by design tightly coupled with a web server context.

Comment: OK, fair enough.  I will revise what I am trying to do.  If you want to add something as an answer, I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to add a file to Request.Files in the Controller

Generally a controller shouldn't have a dependency on `HttpContext`.  Posted files would be included as method parameters on the controller action itself.  That way unit tests can just supply mocks for those parameters (using any mocking library of your choice).  Any coupling to `HttpContext` in the controller, as you can see, makes it quite difficult to test.

However, from your comment above...

> The issue is that a component (which I do not have the source for) does the actual processing of the file directly off of the HttpContext.

In that case don't think of the dependency as being on `HttpContext`, but rather as being on that third party component.  In which case *that* is the thing which would need to be mocked.  If it's not a parameter on the method itself, then a common pattern would be to have a settable property.  Maybe something as simple as this on the controller:

```
private SomeComponent _component;
public SomeComponent Component
{
    get
    {
        if (_component == null)
            _component = new SomeComponent();
        return _component;
    }
    set { _component = value; }
}
```

The code in the controller which uses that component can just reference the property directly without having to worry about setting it.  But the option to set it is there for testability.  The unit test can then create a mock and set it on the controller as part of the test's "arrange" step before invoking any action which uses that component.

That way the code is isolated from dependencies and can be tested by itself.

If, on the other hand, that component *is* what you're trying to test then this starts to become something to discuss with the vendor :)  For starters, third party components should be tested by the vendor before being shipped of course.  (If it isn't, then it's worth questioning the use of that component.)  But aside from that, if you do want to test it then it sounds like that tight coupling is going to make it more of a manual test (which is something about which you can freely complain to the vendor, of course).  `HttpContext` is notoriously difficult to use in tests because it is, by design, coupled to a web server context.